# localhost won't open from WampSever menu

Tags: localhost, wamp

Can't open localhost from WampSever menu, the error is "could not execute run action, the directory name is invalid", but when I type "localhost" directly in address bar in browser, it works fine. For phpMyAdmin as well. The icon in the taskbar is green, everything else works just fine. Any idea what could the problem?

Comment: My guess would be that you have a bad path somewhere in wampmanager.ini - probably the path to your browser.

Comment: @user2748386 It would be nice if you mentioned how you fixed it. Afterall thats the purpose of this site.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had a bad path to my browser. I reinstalled the browser recently, and I changed location, so the path was, well, bad :)